# Large Conditional for placing elements into sections arrays, better approach? - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, conditional-statements

I have this piece of code for placing elements from an array into the appropriate section in a UITableView depending on their starting letter:

```
//For each product in the appDelgates products
for (Product *product in appDelegate.m_Products){
    if ([product.category isEqualToString:productType]){

        //firstLetter is equal to the first letter of the products name
        NSString * l_FirstLetter = [product.name substringToIndex:1];
        //convert firstString to uppercase
        l_FirstLetter = [l_FirstLetter uppercaseString];

        //Check what letter firstString is equal to in the alphabet
        //Place in appropriate section
        //If none, place in "Other" category
        if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:0] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:1] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"C"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:2] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"D"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:3] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"E"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:4] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"F"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:5] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"G"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:6] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"H"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:7] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"I"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:8] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"J"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:9] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"K"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:10] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"L"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:11] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"M"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:12] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"N"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:13] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"O"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:14] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"P"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:15] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"Q"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:16] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"R"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:17] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"S"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:18] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:19] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"U"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:20] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"V"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:21] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"W"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:22] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"X"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:23] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:24] addObject:product];
        }
        else if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"Z"]) {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:25] addObject:product];
        }
        else {
            [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:26] addObject:product];
        }

    }
}
```

Is there a better approach?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

transform the char to an int minus the int of a char of a "A"

and just use `[[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:myInt] addObject:product];`

and make sure, you are only using letters. and If you want to support small and big letters, you have to subtract char of 'a' from small letters.

there are more sophisticated approaches if you need to support locales and diacritics in the future, but this will work for the a…z and A…Z sets defined in the OP:

First, the wordy version which documents how this works:

```
static inline NSUInteger InsertionIndexForProductNamed(NSString * product) {
  assert(0 < product.length && "invalid argument");

  const int A = 'A';
  const int Z = 'Z';
  const int a = 'a';
  const int z = 'z';

  const unichar first = [product characterAtIndex:0];
  const bool isLowercaseAZ = a <= first && z >= first;
  const int uppercase = isLowercaseAZ ? (first + A - a) : first;
  const bool isUppercaseAZ = A <= uppercase && Z >= uppercase;

  if (isUppercaseAZ) {
    const int result = uppercase - A;
    return (NSUInteger)result;
  }
  else {
    /* not A-Z. place in 'other' */
    return 26;
  }
}
```

Now the short version, which is more along the lines of what you may see in the wild:

```
static inline NSUInteger InsertionIndexForProductNamed(NSString* product) {
  assert(0 < product.length && "invalid argument");

  const unichar first = [product characterAtIndex:0];
  switch (first) {
    case 'A'...'Z' :
      return first - 'A';
    case 'a'...'z' :
      return first - 'a';
    default :
      return 26;
  }
}
```

*In use:*

```
/* For each product in the appDelgates products */
for (Product * product in appDelegate.m_Products) {
  if ([product.category isEqualToString:productType]) {
    const NSUInteger idx = InsertionIndexForProductNamed(product.name);
    [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:idx] addObject:product];
  }
}
```

Finally, the short in-line implementation could take this form:

```
/* For each product in the appDelgates products */
for (Product * product in appDelegate.m_Products) {
  if ([product.category isEqualToString:productType]) {
    const NSUInteger insertionIndex;
    const unichar first = [product characterAtIndex:0];
    switch (first) {
      case 'A'...'Z' :
        insertionIndex = first - 'A';
        break;
      case 'a'...'z' :
        insertionIndex = first - 'a';
        break;
      default :
        insertionIndex = 26; // 26 is the index of the 'other' category
        break;
    }
    [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:insertionIndex] addObject:product];
  }
}
```

<sub>please also note my [ObjC/Block-style answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9027644/106435)</sub>

Comment: i added a demonstration. feel free to alter or delete.

Comment: @Justin — quite generous of you! I am not too familiar with C.

Comment: @Justin — I voted up some of your answers, that I found useful, to say thank you. I had to search a bit to find some, I hadn't up voted yet…

Comment: you're welcome, and thanks! the order of events went like this: you answered. i upvoted. you deleted. i went on and wrote a response. when i returned, your answer was un-deleted, so i just added my sample to your answer =)

Comment: the thing is: I just came home from a party. I wrote my answer. and than (as I am a biiiit drunk) I didn't understand, what I wrote anymore. So I deleted it, to make sure, I wasn't a total idiot. and Voila: I had to add a 't' and suddenly it made sense again.

Comment: and being drunk and the new spell checking of Lion together is really hard.

Comment: hahaha. well, i am over-caffeinated atm, so there is some normalization =p that spell checker ultimately needed to be disabled on my machines.

Comment: @Justin — I'd like to know, what you think of my other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9027644/106435)

Comment: I've expanded the answer above to include a real world version of the implementation. Regarding your other answer: Compared to many Cocoa devs (and even C++ devs), I think and write at a very low level -- don't take my resopnse too critically. IMO, the solution is more complicated than it needs to be; Both in source complexity and execution. Personally, I would use the implementation I posted above for the problem in the OP.

Comment: Coming from Python, I prefer high-level. and with blocks I can re-create functional programming style, like list-comprehensions. I really miss things like that in ObjC.

Comment: Despite what my SO weights imply, I'm more of a developer of audio/visual subsystems than a typical iOS developer. I've just had a few years' head start as an OS X developer; I knew ObjC+Cocoa years before iOS. Anyways, there's certainly some overhead to play with in most real world scenarios. Trying to create more expressive systems doesn't hurt :) I've certainly invested a lot of energy in that pursuit myself.

Answer (score 1):

Messing with chars lets you get weird issues where you're adding to objects at indicies which are outside of [0,25], which is a big no-no.  By explicitly declaring your dictionary you can make sure you avoid that.

```
 bool added = NO;
 NSArray* theAlphabet = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C" ... ,@"Z",nil];
 for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
     if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:[theAlphabet objectAtIndex:i]]) {
        [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:i] addObject:product];
        added = YES;
     }
 }
 if(!added)
     [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:26] addObject:product];
```

The `added` flag ensures objects whose first letter isn't a letter are added to array 26.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on vikingosegundo's answer:

```
for (Product *product in appDelegate.m_Products) {
    if ([product.category isEqualToString: productType]) {
        NSString* l_FirstLetter = [product.name substringToIndex: 1];
        l_FirstLetter = [l_FirstLetter uppercaseString];

        NSInteger key = l_FirstLetter - 'A';
        [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex: key] addObject: product];
    }
}
```

This is if Objective-C allows you to subtract a char (`'A'`) from an NSString. You might have to convert `l_FirstLetter` to a char first.

Comment: `NSInteger key = l_FirstLetter - 'A'` is subtracting 'A' from the pointer value of l_FirstLetter.  I think you want characterAtIndex: here.  Also, I'd place a guard around the objectAtIndex: call to prevent out of bounds exceptions

Comment: His first letter might not be a letter.  What if it's a punctuation mark, and suddenly you're trying to add objects at negative indicies?

Answer (score 0):

C provides standard functions for testing for different classes of characters so we can shorten your code to:

```
//For each product in the appDelgates products
for (Product *product in appDelegate.m_Products)
{
   if ([product.category isEqualToString:productType])
   {
       //firstLetter is equal to the first letter of the products name in uppercase
       int l_FirstLetter = toupper([product.name characterAtIndex:1]);

       //Place in appropriate section, if none, place in "Other" category
       unsigned index = isupper(l_FirstLetter) ? (l_FirstLetter - 'A') : 26;
       [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:index] addObject:product];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next to my other [C-style answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9013895/106435) (thanks again, @Justin), I want to postulate another answer.

This time I use objective-c syntax and blocks only.

*Creating an array of words:*

```
NSString *text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,..."; // Lorem ipsum with non-letter words
NSArray *words = [[[text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""] 
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""] 
                            componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

*creating and filling the dictionary:*

```
NSMutableDictionary *wordDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[words performBlock:^(id element) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [[element substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
    if ([firstLetter isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:@"A"] && [firstLetter isLessThanOrEqualTo:@"Z"]){
        if (![[wordDict allKeys] containsObject:firstLetter]) {
            NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
            wordDict[firstLetter] = array;
        }

        [wordDict[firstLetter] addObject:element];
    } else {
        if (![[wordDict allKeys] containsObject:@"other"]) {
            NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
            wordDict[@"other"] = array;
        }
        [wordDict[@"other"] addObject:element];
    }
}];

NSLog(@"%@",wordDict);
```

Note that this code uses a category method on NSArray `performBlock:`. This method does nothing more than apply a block to every element in a array. [It can be found at github](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/arraytools/blob/master/arraytools/NSArray+FunctionalTools.m).

```
-(void)performBlock:(void (^)(id))block
{
    for(id element in self) {
        block(element);
    }
}
```

---

*Output*

```
{
    A =     (
        amet,
        aliquyam,
        At,
        accusam,
        amet,
        amet,
        aliquyam,
        At,
        accusam,
        amet,
        amet,
        aliquyam,
        At,
        accusam,
        amet
    );
    C =     (
        consetetur,
        clita,
        consetetur,
        clita,
        consetetur,
        clita
    );
    //…
    L =     (
        Lorem,
        labore,
        Lorem,
        Lorem,
        labore,
        Lorem,
        Lorem,
        labore,
        Lorem
    );
    //…
    T =     (
        tempor,
        takimata,
        tempor,
        takimata,
        tempor,
        takimata
    );
    U =     (
        ut,
        ut,
        ut
    );
    V =     (
        voluptua,
        vero,
        voluptua,
        vero,
        voluptua,
        vero
    );
    other =     (
        "%$",
        "!",
        "9)7/",
        1234,
        56hfr
    );
}
```